# How to Install Image Magick and GhostScript in Dspace?

Tags: repository, imagemagick, tomcat7, ghostscript, dspace

How to Install Image Magick and GhostScript in Dspace?

How to deploy/configure on Tomcat 7?

I installed the two but do not know how to set it

org.dspace.app.mediafilter.ImageMagickThumbnailFilter.ProcessStarter = /usr/bin

Thank You Guys!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration setting you referenced should point to the directory containing the ImageMagick and GhostScript utilities.

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/ImageMagick+Media+Filters

The ImageMagick filter in DSpace is invoked through the im4java library.  The im4java library invokes these commands as a subprocess.

The class org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter is provided the path you specify in your DSpace configuration file.  After deploying a change to the configuration file, tomcat should be restarted for the configuration change to take effect.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/mediafilter/ImageMagickThumbnailFilter.java#L49